# Creating exact dates in Excel VBA by inputing only the day

Tags: excel, vba, date

In the following picture of an Excel sheet, the heading of the first column, and then of every 7th column after that, contains a month and a year.

[image: my project]

I am trying to think of some code which would make entering complete dates under these headings faster. Since the month and the year are already present, I'm thinking there must be a way to enter just the day, and get the whole thing. For example, if "21" were entered in cell A26, "2/21/2015" would result.

Anyone have an idea for how I might get this output?

Edit: Thanks to the helpful replies on this forum, I figured out exactly how to do this. Here is the code for my finished product, in case anyone wants to do something similar:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Selection As Range)

Set Sel = Selection
If Sel.Count > 1 Then
Exit Sub
End If

If (Sel.Column - 1) Mod 7 = 0 Or Sel.Column = 1 Then
```

'In my case, date columns always follow the pattern of 1, 8, 15...

```
If Sel.Value > 31 Or Sel.Value = "" Then
Exit Sub
Else
Sel.NumberFormat = "General"
Sel.Value = Left(Cells(1, Sel.Column), InStr(Cells(1, Sel.Column), ",") - 1) & " " & _
     Sel.Value & Right(Cells(1, Sel.Column), 6)

     Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: is the month/year in A1 a string or a formatted date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about entering the day numbers, selecting the range where these day numbers are entered, and running the below:

```
Sub Add_month_year()
  Dim c As Range
  For Each c In Selection
    c = Left(Cells(1, c.Column), InStr(Cells(1, c.Column), ",") - 1) & " " & _
    c.Value & Right(Cells(1, c.Column), 6)
  Next
End Sub
```

This should return the full dates in date code, which you can then format as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is just what I need. I'll rig up something to run this code whenever a number is entered into a column with a date heading.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. This link explains one manner in which you might set that up: [Run Macro When Cells Change](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213612)

Comment: Nice; that looks really helpful.